# How do i solve the error "class_name doesn't implement interface_name"?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `MIDIFileKeyEventAccess`, which implements `IList<IKeyEvent>`(`IKeyEvent` is an interface i defined). The code gives me an error [CS0738](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0738) (`MIDIFileKeyEventAccess` does not implement interface member `IEnumerable<IKeyEvent>.GetEnumerator()`. `MIDIFileKeyEventAccess.GetEnumerator()` cannot implement `IEnumerable<IKeyEvent>.GetEnumerator()` because it does not have the matching return type of `IEnumerator<IKeyEvent>`). I've tried changig the return type to `IEnumerator`, but thet doesn't work either
This is my code:

```
public class MIDIFileKeyEventAccess : IList<IKeyEvent>
    {
        private MIDIFile file;

        public MIDIFileKeyEventAccess(MIDIFile file)
        {
            this.file = file;
        }
        public MIDIFileKeyEventAccess(IEnumerable<IKeyEvent> content, string filePath)
        {
            file = new MIDIFile(filePath);
            file.keyEvents.AddRange(content);
        }

        public IKeyEvent this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                return file.keyEvents[i];
            }
            set
            {
                file.keyEvents[i] = value;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return file.keyEvents.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(IKeyEvent item)
        {
            file.keyEvents.Add(item);
        }

        public int IndexOf(IKeyEvent item)
        {
            return file.keyEvents.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, IKeyEvent item)
        {
            file.keyEvents.Insert(index, item);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            file.keyEvents.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            file.keyEvents.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(IKeyEvent item)
        {
            return file.keyEvents.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(IKeyEvent[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            file.keyEvents.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public bool Remove(IKeyEvent item)
        {
            return file.keyEvents.Remove(item);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return file.keyEvents.Count;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IList)file.keyEvents).IsReadOnly;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add definition for `MIDIFile`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as that:

```cs
public IEnumerator<IKeyEvent> GetEnumerator()
{
    return file.keyEvents.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netcore-3.1) implements both [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1) and [non-generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1) versions of `IEnumearble`, so you need to implement both generic and non-generic version of `GetEnumerator`:

```
    public IEnumerator<IKeyEvent> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return file.keyEvents.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() // explicit interface implementation
    {
        return file.keyEvents.GetEnumerator();
    }
```